# Why, even after his imprisonment, do people keep calling Hannibal Lecter "Doctor"?

Tags: the-silence-of-the-lambs, hannibal, red-dragon

In *"The Silence of the Lambs"*, *"Hannibal"*, and *"Red Dragon"* almost every character that I remember addresses Hannibal Lecter as "Dr. Lecter", even after he was imprisoned for being a serial killer. Wasn't his medical license revoked? Did they keep calling him "Dr." as a sign of respect? I find it a bit odd that this aspect wasn't taken into consideration...

Comment: Why is it such a surprise? I mean, you don't expect medical advice from every person you call "Doctor" in real life, do you?

Comment: @M.A.R. not even Dr Pepper?

Comment: As usual, the answer can be found in an Austin Powers movie: "It's Dr. Evil: I didn't spend six years in Evil Medical School to be called 'mister', thank you very much."

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### It's a matter of respect

Even if his medical **licence to practice** has been revoked he is still a qualified doctor, having earned a medical degree, and so is *entitled* to be called "Doctor".

However, it's also a matter of maintaining equilibrium with him on a daily basis. [**Respect**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76398/why-does-dr-hannibal-lecter-respect-clarice-in-silence-of-the-lambs?rq=1) 
and proper manners are highly important to Lecter and treating him with disrespect (or indeed to people he likes) or bad manners is likely to make him very difficult to deal with.

When Clarice is disrespected by Miggs in the prison Lector tells her:

> Discourtesy is unspeakably ugly to me.

and essentially talks Miggs into suicide.

Comment: This makes sense, although Chilton doesn't seem to respect Lecter very much...

Comment: @Ethan the feeling is mutual, Lecter really hates Chilton!

Comment: In TSOTL and RD especially, the FBI needs Lecter to solve cases, so there is greater incentive to show him the respect he wishes to receive, but I also entirely agree that many generally come to respect him, despite how dangerous he actually is, hence Clarice's interactions and approach in "Hannibal"...

Comment: It is not a medical degree which entitles one to be called "Doctor", it is any academic doctorate degree.  The term and title far precede the existence of any M.D.  A medical degree confers the term "Physician" and the right to apply and be tested for a medical license.

Comment: *We salute the rank, not the man.*

Comment: @RBarryYoung Getting pretty far into Quibbleville, but they didn't say only medical degrees entitle you to the title "Doctor," only that Lecter is entitled because he earned a medical degree.

Comment: The surname is *Lecter*.

Comment: @AzorAhai, no, my comment above is precisely correct: There are other medical degrees that are not doctorates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_degree#targetText=Primary%20medical%20degrees&targetText=Such%20degrees%20include%3A,Doctor%20of%20Osteopathic%20Medicine%20(DO)).  It is the doctorate degree that entitles "Doctor", *not* that the degree is for medicine.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Note that what you say is correct in the US, but not UK.  Most General Practitioners are called "Doctor", but do not have a doctorate.  (Some medical practioners, _do_ have doctorates though.)

Comment: @RBarryYoung Fair enough, I was not aware of the bachelor's degrees called "medical degrees," in the US (where *SotL* is set), I think most people would only think of MDs/DOs when you say "medical degrees."

Comment: @RBarryYoung: It's true that an academic doctorate entitle you to the honorific prefix "Dr.", but at least in the U.S., relatively few people use that prefix outside of an academic context. By contrast, medical doctors often use the title "Dr." even outside a medical context. (This was especially the case back when the use of titles like "Dr." and "Mr." was more common in everyday life: academics would be "Dr." inside the academy and "Mr."/"Mrs."/etc. outside, while medical doctors would be "Dr." everywhere.)

Comment: @Mazura - Nice Band of Brothers reference!

Comment: @Ethan Chilton is a doctor himself, and he comes across as the kind of guy who believes that doctorate puts him above the plebs. He may not respect Lecter, but he can't undermine the status attached to Lecter's doctorate without undermining his own.

Answer (score 16):

Because at some point in his life, he got a Doctorate.

A [Doctorate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorate) is a very high level of college degree.

There are doctorates in almost any collegiate subject. Physics, engineering, data science, geology, psychology, music, etc.  In some cultures a doctor*ate* is required to practice medicine at full privilege (unlike, say, a nurse practitioner in the USA).  Whether the honorific applies to non-doctorate medical doctors, may vary.

### Proper English

Back when manners existed, people were formally addressed as "Mister", "Missus", "Mizz" or "Miss".  *However, when someone has earned a Doctorate, this is replaced by "Doctor".*  Using "Mister" for a doctor is simply wrong.

**All they're saying is "Mister Lecter" *but using correct English*.  Simple as that.**

---

---

### But he's a bad man. Shouldn't we take that away?

No.  Using "Mister" is an insult (not least, against English *itself*). It means a) you don't know, b) you are developmentally impaired, or c) you are intentionally insulting or taunting the doctor in some way. For a good example of the latter, see how the Ancient One speaks to [Doctor Strange](https://www.moviequotesandmore.com/doctor-strange-best-quotes/) during his training.

As for taking the honorific away from bad men, here's what King George V (World War II era) had to say on Britain's highest honorific:

> The King feels so strongly that, no matter the crime committed by anyone on whom the Victoria Cross has been conferred, the decoration should not be forfeited. Even were a [holder of the] VC to be sentenced to be hanged for murder, he should be allowed to wear his Victoria Cross on the scaffold.

It's like that.

Doctorates, once properly earned, are for life and cannot be revoked, because it represents the work that *definitely was done*.  A license to practice medicine is a separate thing, and can be revoked.

Comment: *There are doctorates in almost any collegiate subject. Physics (take Dr. Stephen Hawking), engineering, data science, geology, psychology, music, and medicine. This is required to practice medicine.* This is not exactly correct. A doctorate (an academic title, following a research work ending with a defense) is one thing. A diploma called "doctorate" (such as in France) is another thing, this is a license. Both entitle the holder to be called "Doctor" but the way to get it is vastly different.

Comment: (cont'd) In other countries a "medical doctor" does not get the title of "doctor" before actually having gone though academic research (in Poland for instance)

Comment: Also, Dr Strange did an actual doctorate, in parallel to his medical license.

Comment: Finally, doctorates can be revoked when the title was received via fraud, illegally, etc. Not common, though.

Comment: Stephen Hawking isn't an ideal choice of example of the honorific "Dr." for holders of academic doctorates. It was only the appropriate title by which to address him for the first 8 years early in his career before he received his first professorship, from which point "doctor" was no longer his highest title and he was properly known as Prof. Hawking.

Comment: *Using "Mister" for a doctor is simply wrong.* Until the doctor becomes a surgeon, that is, at which point the correct title is "Mister".  Surgeons are pretty keen on this, because (again) they consider they've earned that title to distinguish them from rank-and-file doctors.  (Which makes it ironic that Doctor Strange does not insist on being called Mister Strange, considering he was a surgeon.)

Comment: Whats funny about the SW reference, is that Hannibal became a fan in the "Hannibal" book series, believing in a now debunked Hawkin's theory of time moving in reverse. The TV adaptation included a few Hawking-esque ideas in it's over all themes and concepts.

Comment: In Germany you will loose a PhD when not behaving well, especially and I would say easily in scientific fields. But a prison sentence is also able to withdraw the doctorate.

Comment: Whether he should actually still hold the title or not, what is more important is that Hannibal thinks he still deserves the title. The people in the story need his cooperation and he has proven to be very dangerous to anyone he perceives as showing him any disrespect. It pays to show him any courtesy he wants.

Comment: @SethR I suspect if you used words like "broked", "ain't", "nucular", etc., he'd not appreciate it either.  God help you if you "axe" him a question...

Comment: @Harper, or play a flute just slightly out of tune in a concert...Really not a guy I want to piss off.

Comment: @Graham As far as I know, using *Mister* for surgeons is a UK distinction. In the US at least, they exclusively go by *Doctor* in my experience.

Comment: It's important to remember that language is _descriptive_, not _prescriptive_, and must follow usage as usage changes.  I caution anyone asserting "correct" English to bear that in mind, otherwise the answer may not age well.

Comment: Hannibal Lecter did not have a doctorate, he had a medical degree, thus making him a physician. He went to medical school and was a psychiatrist.

Answer (score 9):

While I agree with other answers presented, I decided to turn my comment into an answer and go a little deeper into Thomas Harris' objectives on the FBI having incentive to treat Hannibal with respect, but also how that's a theme leading to a more provocative question about humanity and the notion of "civilization" or "civility"...

The first two books released were *Red Dragon* & *The Silence of the Lambs*. Both these works are mirrored works executed with an episodic structure (a specific case of book, if you will) and a larger arc of Hannibal getting caught (*Red Dragon*; at the beginning of the novel) and Hannibal escaping (*The Silence of the Lambs*; at the end of the novel) with Hannibal being asked to consult on both individual cases with two different FBI lead protagonists (Will Graham, Clarice Starling) while incarcerated.

These books have then been adapted into films with *The Silence of the Lambs* having one film and some of its elements have been placed in the *Hannibal* TV series, and *Red Dragon* having two films adaptations and a lot of elements in the TV series.

The reason that is important to answer this question is because

1. All versions/adaptations **provide PROOF of incentive for the FBI to treat Hannibal with the respect** he believes he deserves so that he will help them catch other serial killers (Francis Dolorhyde, James Gumb) in these two cases. Both killers are caught, but Will Graham is initially set up by Hannibal and nearly dies in the process...
2. *Red Dragon* (book and film adaptions) points out that there was an unknown **pre-history** between The FBI/Will Graham/Jack Crawford and Hannibal, implying that **Hannibal was helping them with cases, *before he was caught*** by Will Graham. This is also the basis for the starting point of Bryan Fuller's *Hannibal* TV series, a prequel to *Red Dragon* with Hannibal working with and around the FBI to help them solve cases (and to set them up against other serial killers, as Hannibal is experimenting).  **This helped earned him additional respect** and form attachments and proves that he is **a resource the FBI needs**.
3. **Thematic**. One of Harris' greatest themes with this character is the brutality of Hannibal's actions juxtaposed with a well-kept, jack of many trades (surgeon, psychologist, artist, chef, art collector, philosopher, ala scholarly disposition), verbally-civilized, brilliantly intelligent character. **So Hannibal's infinity for not tolerating rudeness, and therefore promoting "respect", and being able to spread that ideal to those that come to exist around him, is a part of showcasing this theme**. Hannibal is a bit of a Mephistopheles or Faustian character Waring against the limitations of the universe of "God". Harris may be using all of this to ask, *if humans can be spiritually elevated by art and civility or is that a false facade for a more complicated game of survival of fittest, where we are still fighting for power and control among ourselves?* (IMO Harris answers it at the end of the Hannibal novel, but he might regret it since *Cari Mora* (his latest novel) kind of reads like a Clarice/Hannibal revisionist work).